# Wifi connected no internet

Tags: wireless

I have used ubuntu 14.04 lts for quite some time now and i find it pretty cool ... but now i cannot access internet through wifi despite of being connected to a network.
i tried editing /etc/pm/power.d/wireless file but no success.
currently i want my internet access back please help.
thx in advance.

EDIT : 
this is the output for lspco -knn | grep Net -A2

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:1795]
Kernel driver in use: wl
```

Comment: 2 Questions. 1) How are you posting this? On the same network? 2) Do you know that your router is giving off an internet signal? How?

Comment: i'm using another pc to post this ofcourse. also i know that my router is giving an internet signal because i'm using it to write these words now :D

Comment: That doesn't answer either of my questions..

Comment: i hope the above edit answers your questions.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Robert, you legit just took out some spaces, and didn't answer either of my questions.

Comment: answer  : 1) on another pc with the same network 2) yes i know that it's giving off an internet signal because i'm using it to access the internet on another pc. @DavidCole

Comment: What operating system, is that 'other PC?'

Comment: windows 10 @DavidCole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer in more detail and in backup in-case of page deletion of [(this answer)](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2303151&p=13391968#post13391968), this is what you should do.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe bcma
```

And then you do:

```
sudo iw reg set EG
sudo sed -i 's/^REG.*=$/&EG/' /etc/default/crda
```